# How do I view only one display at a time, connecting to a two-display system via X2go?

Tags: linux-mint, remote-desktop, x2go

I have a Linux Mint 20 box at work that I want to connect to via X2go. I want to be able to pick up my work where I left off, so I want to access the current desktop, not start a new X session. The issue is that my work computer has two monitors, so when I connect on my laptop, the two monitors are squished into one screen, as shown below. How can I view only one display at a time via X2go and toggle between them?[image]

Comment: Any solution by now?

Comment: No I gave up sry.

Comment: Nomachine worked for me, there I could select the screen at any time